# Simple countdown timer in Mathematica

Tags: date-and-time, timing

I dug around a bit and did not find a simple and clear implementation of  countdown stopwatch in *Mathematica*. I am looking for a function that takes as an input a certain integer and then counts down by 1 every second till 0 is reached. I think it could be an important part for some examples. Kernel or Front End implementations are both acceptable. Here is my take on it:

```
timer[s_] := Module[{x = AbsoluteTime[], y = AbsoluteTime[]}, 
              RunScheduledTask[y = AbsoluteTime[], {1, s}];
              Dynamic[s - Floor[y - x]]]
```

It's a bit hacky but works ;-) I have seen the following questions already:

- [How to make a dynamic stopwatch?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4207/how-to-make-a-dynamic-stopwatch)
- [How can Time be made to go backwards?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8593/how-can-time-be-made-to-go-backwards)
- [Stopwatch in Mathematica?](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Aug/msg00665.html)

but I do not think they do what I was looking for. They either run time forward, are too complex, or something else. Did I miss anything? Does anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about

```
timer[s_] := Dynamic[s - Clock[{0, s, 1}, s, 1]]
```

Comment: +1 Very nice ;) I wonder if there are any other solutions.

Comment: @Rojo Anolther question, but... is it possible to forse *Mathematica* to play a sound when 0 is reached?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov it seems like Clock updates one extra time when it stops. But we can always do `timer[s_] := DynamicModule[{guard = True}, Dynamic[
   If[guard && # === 0, Beep[]; guard = False; #, #] &[
    s - Clock[{0, s, 1}, s, 1]]]]`

Comment: @Rojo how can we make this work so that it does two things: `(Beep[];NotebookSave[])&`?

Comment: @Rojo the following has me perplexed. please help me interpret `If[...]&` and the square brackets of `[clock stuff]`. (1) the cond is `guard && # === 0,` when true is `Beep[]; guard = False; #,` when false is`#` do i have it correct? (2) i understand how the clock works but why no delimiter between `If[...]&` and `[clock stuff]`?` (3) how did you know to wrap clock stuff in square brackets? (4) how can we make this work so that it does two things: `Beep[]` and `NotebookSave[])`? thank you i hope im not asking for too much.

Comment: @Rojo nevermind to questions in previous comment. i figured it by digging into the documentation.